# Clicking on children blurs parent element

Tags: javascript

So Im trying to make a login dropdown but until now I can't. When I click on an input on the dropdown it blurs parent element and disappear.

```
<div tabindex=0 class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Open</a>
  <div><form action="">
    <input type="text">
  </form></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown > a {
  display:relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.dropdown > div{
  display:none;
}

.open > div {
  display: block;
}
```

js

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')).forEach((element) => {
  element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(element.classList.contains('open')){
        element.classList.remove('open')
    } else {
        element.classList.add('open')
      element.focus();
    }
  })

  element.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    element.classList.remove('open')
  })

})
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/owtm649b/6/

Comment: are you using angular? https://myplanet.github.io/angular-deep-blur/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by replacing div blur event for body click event and a stopPropagation when clicks occur on that div.

```
element.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.stopPropagation();
 })

document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        element.classList.remove('open')
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 element.focus();
```

to:

```
element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rfu4dd8t/).

You were bringing focus onto the *a tag* which would **blur** when you focused on the input tag and consequently close the open menu.

Comment: That wont work, being a login dropdown I also have another input, and also a checkbox for remember. So when I change the focus it will disappear